# COBOL field highlighted red on compile - what is this?

Tags: linux, highlight, cobol

I have attempted to compile the following code, and on compile the code turned into a red highlighted mess, for me, as a beginner, what I found odd was that on compile it did not run any errors or warnings. So what is this, what caused it, and how can I fix it?

``
Code:

```
        IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.
        PROGRAM-ID. Exercise1 as "Exercise1".
        AUTHOR. User (040597017).

        DATA DIVISION.
        WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.
        01 Num1      PIC 999 VALUE ZEROS.
        01 Num2      PIC 999 VALUE ZEROS.
        01 Result    PIC 999999 VALUE ZEROS.
        01 Operator  PIC X   VALUE SPACE.

        PROCEDURE DIVISION.
        Calculator.
            PERFORM 3 TIMES
                DISPLAY "Enter First Number (123)  : " WITH NO ADVANCING
                ACCEPT Num1
                DISPLAY "Enter Second Number (234) : " WITH NO ADVANCING
                ACCEPT Num2
                DISPLAY "Enter operator (+) : " WITH NO ADVANCING
                ACCEPT Operator
                IF Operator = "+"
                    THEN ADD Num1, Num2 GIVING Result
                END-IF
                IF Operator = "*"
                    THEN MULTIPLY Num1 BY Num2 GIVING Result
                END-IF
                DISPLAY "Result is = ", Result
            END-PERFORM.
            STOP RUN.

        END PROGRAM Exercise1.
```

``

[image]

compiling, closed and re-opened program

Comment: Just a guess, did the compiler overwrite the source code with the binary?

Comment: thats what I would assume if on compile, my code essentially was replaced with what you see here.  CTRL+z would return my code though

Comment: The "red mess" looks like your IDE is showing the compiled ELF binary. Does your source file have an extension like `.cob` or `.cbl` like the others appear to have?

Comment: it does not have an extension, from the text book, it reads "Create a new COBOL File called Assignment #2".  In this case, should it have an extension?  The only reason I didn't add one is because the previous exercise said to specifically name it "Assignment1.cob".  Maybe I'm just taking it to specific?

Comment: Typically, the source code has an extension depending on the language, `.cob` in your case. The resulting object file has extension `.o` or `.obj`, and the final binary has no extension or `.exe` (on Windows). So, if the source code had no extension, maybe it was overwritten by the compile.

Comment: That's definitely a binary, not a COBOL source file... What does `cobc -V` says? I do know that cobc has parts in that should prevent that, but the "no extension at all" may not be covered.

Comment: You were correct about adding the extension to the filename. that fixed the error